# I am having trouble overriding Firefox default css using userContent.css file

Tags: firefox, css, firefox-profile, firefox-developer-tools

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 with dark theme , Today I have upgraded my firefox to developer edition (40.x)

previously i was on firefox 38.x

I use some of the sites where firefox default **from.css** styling doesn't fit well
specifically text-area, input field and select boxes so in firefox 38 i have created chrome folder and placed userContent.css file inside that and it was working fine

but in this new developer version ( firefox 40.x) .. I did the same thing , Placed my CSS inside chrome folder of newly created profile but nothing is working

userContent.css file is not even loading ...checked in inspector
path

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/ppropqu0.dev-edition-default/chrome
```

below is the content of my userContent.css file

```
@-moz-document domain(elance.com) {
    textarea  {
        -moz-appearance: none !important;
        background-color: White !important;
        color: Black !important;
    }
}
```

tried restarting firefox several times, no tweak seems to working

Comment: I am having this same problem on both of my Windows 10 machines and the other guy in my office who uses userContent.css is also having this issue on his Windows 8 machine. Very frustrating. We are also both using Developer Edition.

Comment: still , i couldn't make it to work...tried everything..and everybody says userContent.css is only way to tweak your firefox's behavior.. (or change file in installation directory in user-agent css)...weird thing is it was working fine in previous versions !

Answer (score 0):

I identified a (disappointing) workaround which worked for both of my computers and my coworker. In *Firefox Developer Edition*...

1. Go to `Settings` > `General` > `Startup`.
2. Enable the option `Allow Firefox Developer Edition and Firefox to run at the same time`.
3. Restart your browser.

Now, *Firefox Developer Edition* will still not recognize your `userContent.css` file—even if you reproduce that file in *Firefox DE*'s own newly-independent profile folder. I still don't know why this is. I will suspect this is to be a bug until I hear otherwise. **But** now you can use the stable *Firefox* release alongside *Firefox DE* and *it* **will** recognize your `userContent.css` file.

In my case and that of my coworker's, we do not use *Firefox DE* on the same webpages for which we use `userContent.css`, so this workaround was acceptable. (This is likely true for most *Firefox DE* users, as it is, of course, for development purposes and why would a developer need to leverage `userContent.css` when he/she can use the *Inspector* or change the very source code itself?)

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox Developer Edition the userContent.css files don't appear to load properly if you have multi-process Firefox Developer Edition enabled (General -> Startup -> Enable multi-process Firefox Developer Edition). Once you disable this it appears to work.